# Binary to Int Linked Lists In Java

Tags: java, linked-list

I have created a Linked List that is to store a binary number in String and covert it to single bits and store in a Link each. My problem is that I have done all of that and I am now trying to create a method to take the bits and covert it to an integer.

The problem is that the binary to integer logic is not working correctly.
For example: If I enter a binary value `00000001` I get my list printed nicely `0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1` but my integer total comes back as '0' when it should be '1'

My Main Method

```
    private  static Scanner input =new Scanner (System.in);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LinkedList LL=new LinkedList();

    char c=' '; 
    int i=0;
    int total=0;

    System.out.println("Enter a  8-Bit Binary Number");
    String s=input.next();

    if(s.length()<8 ||s.length()>8 || s.length()<0 || s.length()==0){
        System.out.println("Error");    
    }

    while(i<s.length()){//start while : breaks string into single bits and stores into a link individually
        c=s.charAt(i);
        LL.addfromTail(new LinkData(c));
        LL.BinarytoInt(new LinkData(c));
        i++;    
    }//end while

    LL.PrintList();
    System.out.println();
```

My LinkedList Class

```
             public class LinkedList {
Link head=null;
int total=0;




    void PrintList(){//start method
        Link curr=head;

        while(curr!=null){//start while
            System.out.print(curr.ld+"|");
            curr=curr.next;
        }//end while
    }//end method



    void addfromHead(LinkData n){//start method

        Link nl=new Link(n);
        if(head==null){
            head=nl;
        }

        else{
            nl.next=head;
            head=nl;
        }
    }//end method



    void addfromTail(LinkData n){
        Link nl=new Link(n);

        if(head==null){
            head=nl;
        }
        else{
            Link curr=head;
            while(curr.next!=null){
                curr=curr.next;
            }
            curr.next=nl;
        }
    }



    /* int BinarytoInt(LinkData ld2){
        Link curr=new Link(ld2);
         curr=head;
        int x=1;
        while(curr.next!=null){
            if(curr.ld.binarybit=='1'){
                total=total+(x*1);
            }
            x=x*2;
            curr=curr.next;
        }//end while
        System.out.println(total);
        return total;
    }
*/



    /*void BinarytoInt(char c){

        Link curr=head;

         int value=128;

         while(curr.next!=null){
             if(c=='1'){
                 total=total+(value*1); 
                 curr=curr.next;
             }//end if

             value=value/2;
         }//end while

        System.out.println(total);
    }*/







}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem/question? What is the part where you have a problem? Please describe it much more detailed.

Comment: I don't think my input is getting called in my binary to int method                          eg: If I enter a binary value 00000001 I get my list printed nicely 0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1 but my total still comes back as '0' when it should be '1'

Comment: I don't entirely understand your code but I am pretty sure something is wrong with the LL.BinarytoInt(new LinkData(c)); line. You are calculating BinaryToInt on a new LinkData, that has a single bit in it, and not on the entire list. You probably want to call BinaryToInt on the first LinkData in the list.

Comment: That was another was I was trying it...when I did it like this   I've still had the same problem                                                                               void BinarytoInt(char c){
  
  Link curr=head;
   
   int value=128;
   
   while(curr.next!=null){
    if(c=='1'){
     total=total+(value*1); 
     curr=curr.next;
    }//end if
    
    value=value/2;
   }//end while
  
  System.out.println(total);

Comment: Can someone guide me to the correct way of getting that method to work please

Comment: Post your `LinkedList` class.

Comment: Added....I've commented the BinarytoInt methods I've been trying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is that you're calling `BinarytoInt()` with a single temp node, instead of traversing the entire `LinkedList`.

Just set `curr` to `head` in the beginning of the method, and there is no need to take a temp node as parameter:

```
//Remove parameter, it's not needed:
void BinarytoInt(){
    int x=128; int i=0;int total=0;
    //Link curr=new Link(temp);
    Link curr = head; //set curr to head reference

    while(curr.next!=null){
        if(curr.ld.binarybit=='1'){
            //total=total+(x*1);  //this is fine
            total += x;  //more elegant
        }
        curr=curr.next;
        x=x/2;  
    }//end while
    System.out.println(total);
}//end method
```

Then, instead of calling `BinarytoInt()` at each iteration, do it after the entire list is populated.  This is necessary in order for each multiple of 2 to line up correctly with each list item:

```
while(i<s.length()){
    c=s.charAt(i);
    LL.addfromTail(new LinkData(c));
    //LL.BinarytoInt(new LinkData(c)); //remove this
    i++;    
}//end while

LL.BinarytoInt(); //Do this after the list is populated

LL.PrintList();
System.out.println();
```

Comment: Thanks.....My previous method I deleted  was exactly like that with the  exception of me having the unneeded parameters. I tried it like this but my integer is still 0 when I enter 00000001. I changed it from LL.addfromTail to addfromHead and it works. Thnaks a lot

Comment: If your `LL.PrintList()` call successfully prints the list, it should work.  I'll run the code and see if there is anything else going on.

Comment: I changed it from addromTail to addfromHead in the main and it work....Thank you for the help.

Comment: No problem would like to pick your brain again sometime. Been coding on the web development side for the past year so a sudden jump back into java has had me quite rusty. Thanks again.

Comment: @EmilleN Sure, no problem!  And by the way, welcome to Stack Overflow!